# Event Log: atapi - the device did not respond within the timeout period - Freeze

Tags: windows-server-2003, raid, windows-event-log

I have a Windows Server 2003 that stops working randomly (displays image on monitor but is completely frozen), all I could found on the event log as causes were an error from atapi and a warning from msas2k3.

The event log entries are:

> Event Type:   Error Event Source: atapi
>   Event Category:   None Event ID:  9
>   Date:     22-07-2009 Time:        16:13:33
>   User:     N/A Computer:   SERVER
>   Description: The device,
>   \Device\Ide\IdePort0, did not respond
>   within the timeout period.
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http : // go.microsoft.com / fwlink / events.asp.
>   Data: 0000: 0f 00 10 00 01 00 64 00
>   ......d. 0008: 00 00 00 00 09 00 04 c0
>   .......À 0010: 01 01 00 50 00 00 00 00
>   ...P.... 0018: f8 06 20 00 00 00 00 00
>   ø. ..... 0020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ........ 0028: 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
>   ........ 0030: 00 00 00 00 07 00 00 00
>   ........
>
> Event Type:   Warning Event
>   Source:   msas2k3 Event Category: None
>   Event ID: 129 Date:       22-07-2009
>   Time:     16:14:23 User:      N/A
>   Computer: SERVER Description: Reset to
>   device, \Device\RaidPort0, was issued.
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http : // go.microsoft.com / fwlink / events.asp.
>   Data: 0000: 0f 00 10 00 01 00 68 00
>   ......h. 0008: 00 00 00 00 81 00 04 80
>   ...... 0010: 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ........ 0018: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ........ 0020: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ........ 0028: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
>   ........ 0030: 01 00 00 00 81 00 04 80
>   ......

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware that this is an old question, but I've replaced many a burnt-out consumer motherboard for this when the user tries overclocking and manages to run the southbridge outside of spec. SATA controller pooches itself and starts to throw these errors.

I'd have a suspicious look at your RAID controller; all the drive-level redundancy in the world won't save you if the controller itself goes Tango Uniform.

Answer (score 0):

The device on ideport0 is timing out.  From your second event viewer error, I'm assuming you have an Intel SAS raid controller?

Have you recently added any new hardware?

Could be a sign of a loose cable to the hard drive.

Could be a hard drive going bad.

You could try something like [PassMark](http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm) to check the SMART info for the hard drives.  Or even better, try [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm) on them

Comment: Yes I have a sas raid controlller, no new hardware have been added and nobody opened the server so I think that the loose cable is not an option.

I entered the raid console at boot and it said that the drives state was "Optimal" and I didn't saw anything on the raid console event log (but it was a bit confusing to check so probably i did it wrong).

I will try to check the SMART info from the drives but is one drive goes bad or dies shouldn't the system continue? after all that is what raid is for... The server in case has a raid1 for the Operative System and radi5 for the data.

Comment: I was looking on the Intel CDs and found out a Intel Raid Web Console and the log has 3 warnings:

Controller ID: 0 Unexpected sense PD = 1:255, CDB = 0x12 0x01 0x00 0x00 0xff 0x00 , Sense = 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00

Comment: At this point, I would try updating the firmware on your raid controller.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I see this message in my event logs, no longer than about 2 months has ever passed without one drive in the array failing.

Have a spare drive to hand (or if it has a hot spare configured, even better) and make sure your backups are good (you never know what might happen...).

You could see if your specific controller has the ability to query each drives S.M.A.R.T status - that might tell you which drive is on its way out, and also again dependant on RAID controller, you may be able to forcibly mark the drive as defunct and swap it out before it goes by itself.

Comment: I had this problem more two or three times and after that it disappeared. 
It has been ok for about 5 months.